# Non-working nginx rewrite rule with multiple params

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule with nginx which rewrites a non-existent image uri to dynamic page with params but failing.

```
/images/395.4b2a-c6b.large-red/car-image.jpg
```

to

```
/thumb.php?param1=4b2a6aa&param2=c6bc&id=395&size=large&color=red
```

Param details in request are:

```
395 . 4b2a        - c6b         . large - red   /blabla-image.jpg
id  . 4 char hash - 3 char hash . size  - color
```

Colours are limited with : red | blue | green

Sizes are limited too   : small | large

My non-working rewrite rule is:

```
location ~* \.(jpg)$ {
   rewrite ^/images/([0-9-]+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}+\.(.*)\-(.*)/(.*)$ /thumb.php?id=$1&param1=$2&param3=$3&size=$4&color=$5 last;
    }
```

What is wrong with this rule? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using Nginx 1.4.2, your location produced an error with the message...

> nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /path/to/conf

It's because, as per [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)...

> If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Fixed it by enclosing the rewrite condition in quotes.

> What is wrong with this rule? Any ideas?

You missed the capturing braces too.

Here's the working solution...

```
rewrite "^/images/([0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}+)\.(.*)\-(.*)/(.*)$" /thumb.php?id=$1&param1=$2&param3=$3&size=$4&color=$5 last;
```

Your solution can be improved further, like...

```
rewrite "^/images/([0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)\-([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)$" /thumb.php?id=$1&param1=$2&param3=$3&size=$4&color=$5 last;
```